# What could be the reason of this stem turning into white in the center areas?

Tags: succulents

The stem stopped growing since 2 days and the flower/leaf is not opening up. I thought it could be thirsty but watering didn't help.

[image: kurdan]

Comment: should that stem even be there? its not part of the Haworthia growing in the pot...

Comment: We didn’t plant anything extra there.